# BestWay The Restart Substrate Node

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

1. After adding the validator node, it may encounter issues preventing it from creating blocks and initiating the next era in the blockchain.

in this case,is there a way to restart the network?
keep the Blocks&State&History(Does not want purge-chain)

2. Operate the Substrate Node as archive-mode, but polkadot.js can't load past information, there are way to get past information??

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide detailed setup steps.

Comment: Regarding the 1, Follow this guide(https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot)

staking.bond -> session.setkeys -> staking.validate

Comment: What are the issues preventing it from creating blocks?

Comment: @AlexBean I don't know root cause, does not receive any error log Just stop it.